# Android KeyPairGenerator RSA encryption time optimization for API versions 18+

Tags: android, performance, encryption, optimization, rsa

My requirement is to securely store a JWT token using Android Keystore for later retrieval. I had used following code to support the older APIs(18+) for key pair generation and encryption

KeyPairGenerator

```
 private void generateKeyForAPIBelowM(final String alias){
    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 50);
    KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(mContext)
            .setAlias(alias)
            .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + alias))
            .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
            .setStartDate(start.getTime())
            .setEndDate(end.getTime())
            .build();
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator
                .getInstance("RSA",ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(spec);
        keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Encryption

```
generateKeyForAPIBelowM(alias);
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding", "AndroidOpenSSL");

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
keyStore.load(null);

KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

My problem is this encryption takes about 3-15 seconds to generate the encrypted key in a device running on Android 4.4 (API 19). But decryption happens almost immediately.

I feel the time taken is lot higher compared to the `AES` and `AES/GCM/NoPadding` encryption in APIs greater than Android M.

Is this time taken can be considered as normal for `RSA` encryption or are there anything I should do to improve the logic?

I tried changing the transformation to `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` but cannot see any significant difference.

If anyone is interested, I referred following code for my implementation
[URL](https://gist.github.com/Diederikjh/36ae22d5fde9d8f671a70b5d8cada90e).

Comment: Generating a RSA key pair is expensive, but is usually not something you need to do that many times. Are you generating new keys for each encryption? If so - why?

Comment: Yes, AES is way faster than RSA, and should be the preferred option when possible. The reason for using RSA is only due to the two keys. Often RSA would be used to exchange a random AES key, that is then used for the actual data encryption.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen, Thanks for the reply. Well, good point. I could avoid key pair generation for each encryption. But how could I keep the generated key pair safely? Inside Key Store? So, before each encryption, I should use my Alias to check whether the key pair exists in the key store. Is that what you suggest?

Comment: Perhaps you should rethink your requirement as to using platforms as old as API level 18? As far as I remember anything below Lollipop (API 21) is not being security patched anymore and if you move your minimum target up to +21 you'll be able to use AES instead and even get the benefit of the new AndroidX Crypto library, making things a bit more easy to work with.

Comment: Apart from that: keys generated inside the Android Keystore can't leave the Keystore - the data you get is merely a reference to the key inside Android Keystore - well unless the device is rooted, but I guess you can't really do anything about that in any case.
You could also require user authentication when using the keys.